# How do I transform integers to audio in .wav format in C?

Tags: c, audio, wav, sample

I'm trying to do an audio compressor using RLE and diferential PCM , I have all the samples with their respective values:
[Picture of:  index, number of samples, sample Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dk8tx.png)

I was wondering if there's a way to transform those sample values into audio. Those values are the amplitude of the wave.

Comment: Write a wav file.  Play the wav file.

Comment: I recommend you to use SDL2_audio for this matter, it will allow you to create a callback function that will playback your samples! Furthermore if you want to record what you have you should implement a little wav write/read functionality using the wav standard.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ standard doesn't have a library for parsing or serialising audio file formats - or any other file formats.

You can write binary files using unformatted output functions for the standard library. What values you need to write and where is defined by the file format. The wav format is defined and documented by Microsoft and IBM in document titled "Multimedia Programming Interface and Data Specifications 1.0". Note that the document contains C code examples that is specific to Microsoft and is not portable to all systems.

Comment: What if I do RLE and diferential PCM with integers first, and then transform them into binary numbers. Would I be able to get the Audio file?

Comment: @Coicu If the file format documentation specifies that's what you should do, then yes. Otherwise, no.

Comment: @Coicu Are you asking how to make a wav file, or how to make audio come out from the speakers?

Comment: @user253751 I'm asking how to make a .wav file in C. Basically, I have an original audio of 345117 samples, and for each sample I have its amplitude saved in a .txt file. I want to compress this .txt file using RLE and Differentia PCM, and then Decompress it. And finally with the Decompressed .txt file get the original Audio in .wav format. I tried it with Matlab and it kinda works, but the Audio is noisy and louder than the original.

Comment: @Coicu Okay, well the .wav file format is pretty simple. Just write a few bytes (I think about 52?) of header information in the right format, then write the audio data. If using 16-bit audio or higher, then pay attention to byte order.